# How to turn on blue GPS bar when my app is using location services in the background?

Tags: objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

My app is requesting "always authorization", and using the standard background location background running mode. The location updates are happening nicely in the background.

When I use Google Maps' navigation in the background, it displays the blue GPS bar above all other content. My app does not show this. I want to inform my users that the tracking is still going in the background, so I want to show this bar to. How can I enable it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS8: Blue bar "is Using Your Location" appears shortly after exiting app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132698/ios8-blue-bar-is-using-your-location-appears-shortly-after-exiting-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer: If you request for "When In Use" authorization, your app will still able to run in the background, but when it does, it will display the blue bar too. If you are using "Always" authorization, the bar does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

That icon is controlled by **iOS**.  The user must have turned on the switch to show the icon whenever an app requests their location.  If they leave that switch off, the icon will not show.

As long as you used `CLLocationManager` and requested 'always authorization', and the user said 'ok', you'll be fine.  Whenever your app requests the location, the icon will show.