# How to hide status bar message when app is using background location services in iOS

Tags: ios, location-services

I want to hide message that appears on status bar in blue colour on iOS devices, when i minimise my app using location services in background mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174042/ios-corelocation-and-geofencing-while-app-is-closed/17174344#17174344

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7

Comment: SASmith , i don't want to change the status bar colour. My problem is When my app uses location services in background mode and if i minimise my app, then status bar highlights with blue colour bar just like when you create Hotspot or minimise a phone call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` instead of `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` on `CLLocationManager` (and provide the related `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in the `info.plist file)`, and then it will not appear either.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27132483/3950397)

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: Mark this answer is correct, for iOS 10, thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible as Apple reminds user that the respective application using his location in background mode. It concerns with privacy policy by apple.

Comment: True only when when using requestWhenInUseAuthorization. requestAlwaysAuthorization doesn't show the bar.