# How to hide Location icon in an iOS app on screens that do not require it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin.ios

I am developing an iOS app with Xamarin.iOS. 
I have granted permissions to use Location Services, and the **Location icon** is visible in the Status Bar as long as the app is running. 
However, my app needs to get the current location **on one screen only** - the rest of the time location is not needed.

Is it possible to **turn off (hide)** the Locations icon **when app is not really using** it?

Answers I found are for old iOS versions or work on jailbroken phones. It is my understanding that Apple is preventing this now. I would appreciate a confirmation if this is at all possible or not. Or if it is possible - some Xamarin / Objective-C /Swift examples would be great.

Comment: please share your code where you are getting location.

Comment: you can check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528831/blue-banner-myapp-is-using-your-location-for-app-that-uses-location-services/27132483#27132483 it will help you

Comment: The location icon shows when an app on the system is using location or has recently made use of location. You can't hide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U mean the airplane ICON in status bar?

This ICON will show when APP using location service, try to stop or remove your location request or mapView, your map SDK have their own interface, like:

`locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`

and be sure other APP not using location service.

but it **NOT** sure the service will stop immediately, location manager just a monitor to system.

Comment: It's an arrow rather than an airplane, though.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer. I ended up adding [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] on all screens, and a [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] on just the one screen I needed. This, plus adding requestWhenInUseAuthorization to info.plist seem to have worked. Indeed, a few seconds are needed before the Location icon disappears, but this is much better than seeing it all the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **requestAlwaysAuthorization** instead of **requestWhenInUseAuthorization** on CLLocationManager.

> NOTE : Provide the related **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** in the
>   info.plist file, and then Blue Banner will not display.